# how to check if a button can be pressed with protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm running automation test using protractor and i'm trying to build the test in a way that the browser will decide how much time it needs to wait before performing an action and i won't need to put static browser.sleep commands.

In my test i have an Iframe with buttons on it.

The steps to press the button is first click on a button that makes that Iframe appear, then switch to the Iframe using browser.switchTo().frame(FRAME) and at last click on the button. 
sometimes when i run the test the button is not clicked, probably because it takes a while for the iframe to load.
I'm using browser.driver.wait in my code to wait for elements to be valid for use, and i try to click on the button in the following way:

```
doActionWithWait(BtnElem,function() {
    BtnElem.click().then(function() {
       //so something
    });
});
```

and the doActionWithWait function looks like:

```
doActionWithWait = function(elem,promise) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      //visibilityOfElementLocated
    browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem), 15000).then(function() {
        browser.driver.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elem), 15000).then(function() {
            promise();
        });
    });
};
```

eventhough i'm waiting for the button to be visible and clickable when i perform the Btn.click() nothing happens.

So my question is what is the proper way to wait for the button to be clickable since working with ExpectedConditions doesn't seem to work.